# Which technique is best used to find optimal split on numeric data to reduced error on group?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a dataset that contains a numeric variable and a binary categorical variable. I want to find the optimal split on the numeric variable that can be used to quickly classify the categories and limit the amount of error.

I have used a decision tree to do this but am wondering if there are better optimization methods out there to do this?

I would like to be able to do this in R but am having trouble how to write the function for this.

Please help me understand the simple optimisation problem. Thanks!

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you provide more detail about your problem at hand? Maybe give an example or show code that you have tried?

Comment: Have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis